Show that function from Sobolev space is coercitive
Let $T:W_0^1([0,1]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$T(u) = \int|u'|^2+\int e^u - \int u^5$$
The first part of the excercise asks to show that T is coercive. I know that $-\int u^5 \geq - ||u'||_2^5$, thus is true that
$$T(u) \geq ||u'||_2^2 + \int e^u - ||u'||_2^5$$
Can you help me find an inequality for the central term to show $T(u) \rightarrow +\infty $ as $||u'||_2 \rightarrow +\infty$?

This functional is not coercive. Take any $u \in W^{1,2}_0(0,1)$ with $u \ne0$ and $u \le0$.
Then
$$
T(tu ) \le t^2 \|u'\|_{L^2}^2 +1- t^5 \|u\|_{L^5}^5,
$$
which converges to $-\infty$ for $t \to +\infty$.
